# Previous date and present date

Tags: java

I am a bit stuck here

I am hashing tokens and storing them to db and that is done in order to show user previous login date and time on the ui.

Use case number : User never logged in -> we should return nothing but we should save the previous date in order to show previous date value on the ui when user logins next time. So the idea is to just always return previous logged in timestamp if tokens are different

```java
public Optional<LocalDateTime> test(HttpServletRequest request, UserEntity userEntity) {
    String token = extractTokenFromHeader(request);
    byte[] hashedToken = hashToken(token);
    LocalDateTime presentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    Optional<TokenEntity> tokenEntity = tokenRepository.findByUserId(userEntity.getId());

    if (!tokenEntity.isPresent()) {
        tokenRepository.save(new TokenEntity()
                .setToken(hashedToken)
                .setUserId(userEntity.getId())
                .setPresentTimeStamp(presentTime)
                .setPreviousTimeStamp(presentTime));
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    if (!Arrays.equals(hashedToken, tokenEntity.get().getToken())) {
        tokenRepository.save(tokenEntity.get()
                .setToken(hashedToken)
                .setPreviousTimeStamp(tokenEntity.get().getPreviousTimeStamp())
                .setPresentTimeStamp(presentTime));
        return tokenEntity.map(TokenEntity::getPreviousTimeStamp);
    }
    return tokenEntity.map(TokenEntity::getPreviousTimeStamp);
}
```

TokenEntity has those two fields

```java
@Column(name = "previous_timestamp")
private LocalDateTime previousTimeStamp;

@Column(name = "present_timestamp")
private LocalDateTime presentTimeStamp;
```

Repository have custom method added which locates token entity by user id

```java
public interface TokenRepository extends JpaRepository<TokenEntity, Long> {
    Optional<TokenEntity> findByUserId(Long id);
}
```

Comment: "I am a bit stuck here" is not a question.  What is it that this code does, and what is it that you expect it to do that is different from that?  If you want the best shot at getting a useful answer to your question, please consider posting a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hey @Steve 
1) I am hashing tokens and saving them to db.
2) The reason tokens being stored is to because i am returning previous login value to the ui, so when user logs in he/she should always see last login date

Comment: I understand the basic behavior you're trying to get, but your last comment doesn't help me to understand what the problem is that you're trying to solve here in terms of the code itself.  Can you provide a complete example that I or someone else can actually run?  If not, can you at least explain what your problem is...that is, what behavior you're getting and what behavior you desire?

Comment: Although I don't know just what the TokenEntity object and the repository look like, this code looks more or less reasonable to me.  That's why I need more to go on to know how to help you.

Comment: @Steve i have added it but its not really about whats inside those two data types
In general the expectation is to return previous logged in time on the ui if user logged in for the second time

Comment: But @okey1992, what IS IT THEN?  I still don't see a succinct question here?  I still have no idea what your problem is.  Maybe I'm missing something and someone else gets it, but I'd like to help, and I have no clue as to what you're asking. Even saying something like "the code always creates a new TokenEntry" would be making progress, although it still wouldn't be enough as I can't see the data coming in or the backing code to know why it would be doing that.

Comment: BTW, the first instance of the line `return tokenEntity.map(TokenEntity::getPreviousTimeStamp);` is unnecessary, and I think an understanding of what you're doing would be clearer without it.  Without it, it would be clear that even if the token is different, you want to return the original timestamp.  As it is now, someone has to put 2 + 2 together by recognizing that the two return statements are the same.

Comment: @Steve continue in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221061/discussion-between-steve-and-okey1992).

Comment: `.setPreviousTimeStamp(tokenEntity.get().getPreviousTimeStamp())` shouldn't that be `.setPreviousTimeStamp(tokenEntity.get().getPresentTimeStamp())`. Otherwise you are actually storing the time stamp before the previous one.

Comment: @Marcono1234 jesus body, yes instead of taking present time from the entity i was  throwing present time there like the current time, this is helped